# TypeError: string indices must be integers - json

Tags: python-3.x, woocommerce

I want get value (abc.com/p/B3N) from this json :

```
{'id': 123456, 'parent_id': 0, 'number': '23856', 'order_key': 'abc', 'created_via': 'checkout', 'version': '3.6.4', 'status': 'processing', 'currency': 'USD', 'date_created': '2019-10-05T13:18:49', 'date_created_gmt': '2019-10-05T13:18:49', 'date_modified': '2019-10-05T13:19:20', 'date_modified_gmt': '2019-10-05T13:19:20', 'discount_total': '0.00', 'discount_tax': '0.00', 'shipping_total': '0.00', 'shipping_tax': '0.00', 'cart_tax': '0.00', 'total': '0.40', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'prices_include_tax': False, 'customer_id': 0, 'customer_ip_address': '111.101.111.111', 'customer_user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-J337P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/10.1 Chrome/71.0.3578.99 Mobile Safari/537.36', 'customer_note': '', 'billing': {'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'company': '', 'address_1': '', 'address_2': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'postcode': '', 'country': '', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'phone': ''}, 'shipping': {'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'company': '', 'address_1': '', 'address_2': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'postcode': '', 'country': ''}, 'payment_method': 'paypal', 'payment_method_title': 'PayPal', 'transaction_id': '851R', 'date_paid': '2019-10-05T13:19:20', 'date_paid_gmt': '2019-10-05T13:19:20', 'date_completed': None, 'date_completed_gmt': None, 'cart_hash': '0675772a1e', 'meta_data': [{'id': 123456, 'key': 'is_vat_exempt', 'value': 'no'}, {'id': 123456, 'key': 'Payment type', 'value': 'instant'}, {'id': 274929, 'key': '_paypal_status', 'value': 'completed'}, {'id': 123456, 'key': 'PayPal Transaction Fee', 'value': '0.32'}], 'line_items': [{'id': 10927, 'name': 'Jeans', 'product_id': 1234, 'variation_id': 0, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '0.10', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '0.10', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 100000, 'key': '', 'value': 'Views  $0.00 × 500'}, {'id': 100001, 'key': '', 'value': 'Worldwide'}, {'id': 100002, 'key': '', 'value': 'abc.com/p/B3N'}, {'id': 100003, 'key': '', 'value': '17'}], 'sku': '', 'price': 0.1}], 'tax_lines': [], 'shipping_lines': [], 'fee_lines': [{'id': 10928, 'name': 'PayPal Fee (Free Fee for order over $5)', 'tax_class': '0', 'tax_status': 'taxable', 'amount': '0.3', 'total': '0.30', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 122543, 'key': '_legacy_fee_key', 'value': 'paypal-fee'}]}], 'coupon_lines': [], 'refunds': [], '_links': {'self': [{'href': 'abc.com'}], 'collection': [{'href': 'abc.com'}]}}
```

this is my code

```
    m = (wcapi.get(order + ordernumber).json())
    n = json.dumps(m)
    o = json.loads(n)
    for i in o:
        if i['id'] == '100002':
            print(i['value'])
            break
```

and i got this error :

```
    if i['id'] == '100002':
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

i have searched others topics but ... can't. thanks for help me!

Comment: Before the error line, can you print `i` out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `for i in o` and `o` is a dictionary, the for loop iterates over the keys in `o` - which are strings in your case. Hence the error. `i` is a string.

To get the key you need to know the exact structure of `o`.

I'm gonna give you some examples:

```
o['id'] # 123456
o['billing']['email'] # "abc@gmai.com"
```

Now to get the value you want:

```
first_line_items_meta = o['line_items'][0]['metadata']
for item in first_line_items_meta:
   if item['id'] == 100002:
      print(item['value'])  # "abc.com/p/B3N"
```